# Не работает matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

Не работает matplotlib. Сижу на Ubuntu 18.04. Устанавливал методом pip3 install matplotlib. Удалил и попробовал поставить с помощью sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib. И та же самая ошибка.

```
import math
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(range(20), range(20))
plt.show()
```

Пишет ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если это PyCharm,то могу помочь мб

Comment: да это PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй : File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter

Проверь в списке matplotlib(синяя стрелочка апдейт библиотеку)

А если ее нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажми + и в окне поиска ищи matplotlib и install package

Comment: Не помогло. Та же самая ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло удаление папки matplotlib по адресу /home/user/.cache/.matplotlib